# how to detect long gesture on annotationView in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, sdk

I am working on MapView & I want to add longGesture on annotationView to delete particular annotation,For this I added longGesture on each annotationView in delegate
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapview viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation

but annoattaionView does not detect long gesture.Is there any way to add long gesture on AnnotationView in mapview?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `MKAnnotationView` alredy has a long gesture recognizer for dragging it, therefore depending on the duration (not sure the duration for dragging is), it will go to that gesture recognizer instead, if you do not need dragging you can simply remove that long gesture recognizer by getting all gesture recognizers of the view and then doing a `isKindOfClass` for `UILongGesture`, removing it and then add your own.

Alternativelly trying a low time on the `UILongGesture` might work.

If you don't need the default behavior of gesture recognizers of MKAnnotationView you can also disabled the annotation view like this:

`[myAnnotationView setEnabled:NO];` and then add your recognizer to the annotation view.

Hope that helps.